# Why are PHP-Files not blocked by .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

It occurs to me, that when blocking IPs in the .htaccess file, files of pretty much every filetype are blocked, i.e. .html, .css, .js, .jpeg, .png. But not .php

My .htaccess file looks as follows:

```
# Directory Index

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html


# Error Documents

ErrorDocument 404 /error_404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error_403.php
ErrorDocument 503 /error_503.html


# PHP Settings

# php_value memory_limit 1G
# php_value upload_max_filesize 800M
# php_value post_max_size 900M


# Force www at the beginning of the url

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


# Block IPs

order deny,allow
deny from 62.219.8.226
```

So with IP 62.219.8.226 I can still access the .php-files on the server but nothing else. Anyone knows why this could be?

Comment: @hellcode it is the complete file, although there might be some more denied addresses...

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from 62.219.8.226
```

Comment: Did you some configuration in httpd.conf?